# Searching for a sentence in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write some VBA for an Excel file that looks for a specific phrase/sentence in the column header and changes that phrase/sentence if it finds it. The issue is that sometimes the file won't have the phrase I'm searching for, and the VBA throws an error. Here is my code:

```
Dim srch As Range

   srch = Cells.Find(What:="Usage Charge (Overage Charges)", After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If Not srch Is Nothing Then
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Usage Group Overage"
  End IF
```

This works fine when "Usage Charge (Overage Charges)" exists in the worksheet, but if it doesn't then I get an error telling me the object doesn't exist.

Is there a way to get this simply to do nothing if that phrase doesn't exist?

Comment: Is **"Usage Charge (Overage Charges)"** really only *part* of the column header label? Seems more likely it would be the cell value in its entirety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to use an error handler:

```
Dim srch As Range

On error goto ErrH

 srch = Cells.Find(What:="Usage Charge (Overage Charges)", After:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

If Not srch Is Nothing Then
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Usage Group Overage"
End IF

Exit sub

ErrH:
  ' Do nothing

End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few choices. The first two use wildcards but only replace 1 instance. They would have to be looped. The third replaces all byt depends upon an exact match (no `xlPart`).

```
Sub optimal()
    Dim srch As Range, str As String, rpl As String

    str = "Usage Charge (Overage Charges)"
    rpl = "Usage Group Overage"
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'check if it exists using COUNTIF with silcards
        If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Rows(1), Chr(42) & str & Chr(42))) Then
            'replace 1 occurance value directly
            .Cells(1, Application.Match(Chr(42) & str & Chr(42), .Rows(1), 0)) = rpl
        End If

        'check if it exists using MATCH with silcards
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Chr(42) & str & Chr(42), .Rows(1), 0)) Then
            'replace 1 occurance value directly
            .Cells.Find(what:="Usage Charge (Overage Charges)", After:=ActiveCell, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) = rpl
        End If

        'use if "Usage Charge (Overage Charges)" is the entire cell content
        'replaces all occurances
        .Rows(1).Replace what:=str, replacement:=rpl
    End With

End Sub
```